# Creating a thread-safe wrapper for an executable closure

Tags: rust, closures, type-parameter

I want an arbitrary input, `F`, that returns an arbitrary value, `Z`. From the API perspective, I want something like this:

```
let mut action = ExecutableAction::create(move || {
    true
});
```

In this case, `Z` is an instance of `bool` and `F` is a function which returns `Z`.

I tried this code:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

pub struct ExecutableAction<F, Z>
where
    F: FnMut() -> Z + Send + Sync,
{
    action: Arc<Mutex<Box<F>>>,
}

impl<F, Z> ExecutableAction<F, Z>
where
    F: FnMut<()> + Send + Sync,
    Z: Send + Sync,
{
    pub fn create(closure: F) -> Self
    where
        F: FnMut() -> Z + Send + Sync,
    {
        Self {
            action: Arc::new(Mutex::new(closure)),
        }
    }

    pub fn call(&mut self) -> Z {
        self.action.lock().call()
    }
}
```

```
error[E0658]: the precise format of `Fn`-family traits' type parameters is subject to change. Use parenthetical notation (Fn(Foo, Bar) -> Baz) instead (see issue #29625)
  --> src/lib.rs:12:8
   |
12 |     F: FnMut<()> + Send + Sync,
   |        ^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm sure my syntax is off, as it does not compile. How could I go about making this generically applicable? Also, what about denoting the arguments of `F` with a type parameter `R`? How might this be added on here?

Comment: **Please** include all of the code needed — I had to add `use` statements. **Please** include the error you are getting.

Comment: TL;DR the duplicates: You are using an unstable syntax; use the syntax that you used on the function (`F: FnMut() -> Z`), not on the type (`F: FnMut<()>`). You then have to add a `Box::new`; you can't use `call()` (also unstable); you have to handle the error from `lock`; then work around an issue regarding `DerefMut`. It's unclear why you have duplicated the bound on `F` in two places. [All together, it looks like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=70570f1b7f5d871bdba5dfb3d252222f).